# Nothing shows up

Tags: help

I am trying to use Tor Browser. I've tried to get to one or two sites. When I use the browser, it loads, then it acts like it is done. However, I am just getting empty white displays -- the websites don't resolve -- I can't see anything.

Does anyone know why no websites would show at all?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to get to websites such as https://check.torproject.org/ or other well known sites which you'd know are certainly online?